# How to recognize the square with smaller area?

Tags: matlab

I just wanted to recognize the smaller squares group of squares, I needed some tips for that effect.thaks

```
 I = imread('q1.jpg');
Ibw = ~im2bw(I,graythresh(I));
Ifill = imfill(Ibw,'holes');
Iarea = bwareaopen(Ifill,100100);
stat = regionprops(Iarea,'boundingbox');
imshow(I); hold on;
for cnt = 1 : numel(stat)
    bb = stat(cnt).BoundingBox;
    rectangle('position',bb,'edgecolor','r','linewidth',2);
end
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to get the area of each bounding box and select the minimum? Have you tried anything? What are your thoughts? Please show some effort.

Comment: I already managed to detect what I wanted, but the script captures more information and it is this information that I wanted to eliminate, I wanted to delimit the maximum area.

Comment: What steps have you attempted to achieve your goal? Do you know how to find the area of a bounding box? Do you know how to find the minimum/maximum of those areas? (After your last comment I'm confused as to whether you want the minimum or the maximum bounding box.) What *specifically* is your question?

Comment: As @beaker said, it's not clear what your exact question is, but if your question is identifying the smallest rectangle, you could examine the variable 'bb' for each of your rectangles. It is a vector with four values that contain [x y w h]. Multiplying the w and h values should give you the area of each rectangle which should then help you identify the one with the smallest area.